# Send QImage from c++ client to python server

Tags: python, c++, qimage, tcpsocket

The c++ client has QImage which must be sent via a tcp socket to the python server and saved in jpeg there. The server does not use qt. Could you explain how to do this correctly? How do I write data from QImage to the socket and how do I read it in python for later saving? 
QImage is a little unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be converting `QIMage` to `base64` data and you can de-serialize this later in python side:

in c++ side

```
QByteArray byteArray;
QBuffer buffer(&byteArray);
image.save(&buffer, "PNG"); // writes the image in PNG format inside the buffer
QString iconBase64 = QString::fromLatin1(byteArray.toBase64().data());
```

in python side:

```
# For both Python 2.7 and Python 3.x
import base64
with open("imageToSave.png", "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(base64.decodebytes(img_data))
```